# Programatically Change Criteria Dynamically in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, scheduled-tasks

I have an Access database that has a series of queries that build a list of inventory items that go into a report.  I have a macro that runs all of the queries and emails the report to one of my company's stores in the middle of the night so that the employees at the store can count the items when they arrive in the morning.  I run the macro automatically from the Windows Task Scheduler at the appropriate time in the middle of the night.

However, this method is a bit clumsy.  I currently have a copy of the database for each store.  Each time I send out counts, I have to manually change the vendors' criteria inside of the queries for each copy for each store.  It is very time consuming.

Is there a way I could programatically change the criteria in each query?  I know I can set up a pop-up to prompt the user to input the data.  I could also build a form that prompts for that information.  In a perfect world, my boss would like me to be able to give me a spreadsheet with a store number, a time and date, and a list of vendors and have a single copy of access spit out the report.  However, even an idea for me to do a quick "Find and Replace" would save me a ton of time and the effort of training someone else to dig around in a query.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35064355/78522

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all the criteria in a table.  Open the table and loop through it.  Something like:

```
Set rec = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("Select * from MyCriteriaTable")

Do While rec.EOF = False
    strSQL = "Select * From MyTable Where MyField1 = '" & rec(1) & "' AND MyField2 = '" & rec(2) & "'"
    MyReport.RecordSource = strSQL

    rec.MoveNext 
Loop
```

This is "aircode" and won't work as written, but that's the general idea.